# pyinstaller QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available drivers:

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller, qsqldatabase

I have witten a GUI app using pyqt5 and includes a QtSql database QSQLITE. The app works perfectly. However when I run pyinstaller to a package my app, the app runs until the time where it has to invoke QtSQL DATABASE QSQLITE. This is the error I get

QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:

How do I load the driver so that it can be included when I run pyinstaller.

Thank you

Comment: You should post the section of code where the sqlite driver is loaded.

Comment: @MalloyDelacroix The problem is not related to the code but to `Pyinstaller`. I actually experiencing the same problem but with `QMYSQL driver` and using `PySide`. The application works fine into a python interpreter but this error appears when running the executable created with `PyInstaller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with `QMYSQL driver` using `PySide` and I found a solution.

You need to manually include the driver into the `qt4_plugins/sqldrivers/` bundle directory.
For that, in your spec file add :

```
a = Analysis(...
    binaries=[('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so', 'qt4_plugins/sqldrivers')],
    ...
)
```

This will works for `QMYSQL` driver but you just need to find the name of the `SQLITE` driver (probably `libqsqlsqlite`)

Comment: Thanks for the response Loic. I just tried your solution and it seems to work. I also discovered that if I compile pyinstaller in a virtual environment with a fresh install of pyqt5 and python. The drivers are automatically added. Thanks